# Excel VBA using Selenium - click on href link

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I want to `Click` on href "add_record.php" by VBA Excel Selenium.

Inspect of Targeted site:

```
<li class="active">
<a href="lab_dashboard.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
<li class=""><a href="add_record.php"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Add New Record</span></a></li>
<li class=""><a href="fetch_srf_record.php"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Add Record from SRF Portal</span></a></li>
<li class=""><a href="list_records.php"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>List/Edit/Followup</span></a></li>
<a href="#">
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far, and what issues did you encounter?

Comment: Was your question resolved?

Comment: Thanks Man, it's solved now

Comment: @vitaliis if I have to find all href links in a particular class or id ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to click this element use css selector. `*` means finding any text as specified after `=`.

```
driver.findElementByCssSelector("a[href*=add_record]").Click
```